# Jquery scrolltop Loop between anchors

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to make a loop between the anchors in order to scroll to each one after x milisecs? Actually I am using several functions like

```
setTimeout( function() {
   $('html, body').animate({
       'scrollTop': $('#2').offset().top
   }, 2000);
}, 5000);
```

but after reach the final one I don't know how to start over.

Answer (score 0):

After find a messy and temporary solution that came up with a new issue, that i was trying to solve on another question, itzmukeshy7 kindly solved everything on the other post, so instead of leave my temporary solution, i copy here the link to the right answer to both questions:

[The Right Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002661/jquery-scrolltop-to-multiples-id-settimeout)