# Jquery ScrollTop to multiples ID + SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my case, i have a page with mutiples div/id created from a php while loop, based on the amount of pdf files that exists on a folder. My goal is to scroll to each one of the IDs each 5 secs and then restart the scrolling from the beginning. The following code work ok, but the problem is that if i add 5 new files to the folder then i would need to copy five times the function and what i am looking for is to scroll in order to all the available IDs on the document. There is any way to write a function to do this? Any lights will be appreciated.

This is my actual code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        function loopanchors() {

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    'scrollTop': $('#1').offset().top
                }, 2000);
            }, <?php echo $pdf_time; ?>);

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    'scrollTop': $('#2').offset().top
                }, 2000);
            }, <?php echo $pdf_time*2; ?>);

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    'scrollTop': $('#3').offset().top
                }, 2000);
            }, <?php echo $pdf_time*3; ?>);

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    'scrollTop': $('#4').offset().top
                }, 2000);
            }, <?php echo $pdf_time*4; ?>);

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    'scrollTop': $('#5').offset().top
                }, 2000);
            }, <?php echo $pdf_time*5; ?>);

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    'scrollTop': $('#6').offset().top
                }, 2000);
            }, <?php echo $pdf_time*6; ?>);

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    'scrollTop': $('#7').offset().top
                }, 2000);
            }, <?php echo $pdf_time*7; ?>);

            x = setTimeout(function () {
                loopanchors()
            }, <?php echo $pdf_time*8; ?>); //will loop every 5 seconds.
        }

        loopanchors(); //start it up the first time

    });
```

Comment: $pdf_time is just a 5000 ms variable so i just multiply by the same ID in order to go progressive.

Comment: You can use loop to remove repetition of code;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code adjust $pdf_time & totalPDF as per your need:

```
<script>
  var totalPDF = 7;
  var currentPDF = 0;
  var loopInterval = <?php echo $pdf_time; ?>;
  $(function(){
    function loopanchors(){
      if(totalPDF <= currentPDF++){
        currentPDF = 1;
      }

      /* scroll to currentPDF */
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('scrolling to', currentPDF);
        try{
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#' + currentPDF).offset().top
          },
          2000);
        }catch(e){
          console.log('element not found');
        }

        /* scroll next pdf */
        loopanchors();
      }, (loopInterval * currentPDF));
    }

    /*start it up the first time*/
    loopanchors();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i am not able to make it run

Comment: Try the updated code; if you want to set scrolling amount same for all pdfs update this `}, (loopInterval * currentPDF));` to `}, (loopInterval));`

Comment: Work like a charm! Thanks! I only modified var totalPDF = 7 to var totalPDF = $(".pdf_container").length; to get the actual number of div containing the pdf generated from the php loop. Again Thanks!